# Sitecore - Is there a way to clone/duplicate a user in the User Manager?

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I have an account setup exactly the way I'd like a number of individuals accounts setup and I'd like to create them as clones of this account so the get the initial set of permissions without me having to manually set all the permission on each account.

Note: It is fine (ideal?) if once the accounts are created that they no longer have a relationship with the original account.  For instance, if User A is the base account that is being used to create all the other accounts, once User B is made from User A then all further changes on User A will not be reflected on User B.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your question: ***no, there is no clone/copy user feature in the User Editor in Sitecore.***

It sounds like you would be better off creating a role with all these permissions, then assigning this role to any new users you create. You could then modify the permissions of the individual users as necessary.

*Note this would not be the ideal solution as it's always better to apply security to roles rather than individual users.*

Perhaps you could achieve what you need by creating a collection of roles and assigning different combinations of them to each user?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this Sitecore Module.This will clone the user in User Manager
[SITECORE USER CLONE](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/S/Sitecore_User_Clone.aspx)

Sitecore User Clone is used to create the copy of the user with the same roles, name, email, and profile. It will prompt to accept the new username, password and all the editable fields same like Edit user.